# C++ What to do when a derived class doesn't implement a function from interface

Tags: c++, inheritance

I hope this question wasn't already answered elsewhere, I did search for an answer, but couldn't quite formulate the search properly.

The problem is, I have a Weapon abstract class with the stats a weapon needs (like accuracy, damage, etc). It's an abstract class because some weapons have different implementation to reloading and damage, but the majority of them don't.

The Weapon class has a DoT (a struct) member, along with getDoT member function.

The problem is, not all weapons have a DoT. But at some point in the code, when dealing with attacks, the Weapon::getDoT gets called. Of course, I added a "has_DoT()" method before, so I don't deal with an unitialized DoT object, but this is a rather bad solution.

What's the best way to deal with this? When not all your derived objects actually have the members in the abstract class?

I thought about not having the DoT member/getDoT member function in the first place, and just implement them on a derived class Weapon_With_DoT, but since my abstract class is Weapon, I would still need a check to see if the the weapon has a DoT, and then typecast from Weapon to Weapon_With_DoT to access the Weapon_With_DoT::getDoT member function. It's also unelegant, just the other way around.

I hope the question was explained in a sufficiently clear way. :)

Comment: if not all weapons have DoT then it probably shouldn't be in the top-level abstract class.  Is there a subclass of weapons that have that attribute?  I'd be thinking about why some weapons have that attribute and some don't from a design perspective.

Comment: Joe is absolutely correct.  A top-level abstract class should be used to define common behavior.  Differences like this should be defined at a lower level.

Comment: In hindsight, it does make sense that only common behavior is defined in the interface, but how would you deal with the issue, if the rest of your code uses weapon as the interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DoT stands for Damage over Time, right?  So I imagine it is an object with stats for the damage over time, and it has attributes the amount of damage and the amount of time.

**Option 1: Null object**

Let the Weapon class have a `getDoT` method.  Weapons that don't have DoT could still return a DoT object with zero and/or neutral values for all of its fields.  The code that uses the DoT and knows what those fields are can detect this condition with an if statement and do the proper thing (e.g. if the damage amount is zero, then return before having any effect).

This would be an example of the [Null Object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

**Option 2: Predicate method**

Let the Weapon class have a `hasDoT` method that returns a bool and a `getDoT` method that returns the DoT.  You said this is what your code currently looks like.  I know it is not a popular solution, but it is easy to understand and it gets the job done, so you shouldn't be embarrassed about it.

I would probably add an assertion or throw an exception to catch the situation where `getDoT` is called on a weapon that does not have DoT.

**Option 3: Abstract class**

Put the `getDoT` method in an abstract class.  This class can either be its own thing or it could be a subclass of `Weapon`, depending on what makes sense for your application.  You can use some form of dynamic casting to convert from a `Weapon` pointer to a pointer of the right type.  Other answers have more details about how to do this.

This is actually the least flexible option because it assumes that we know which weapons have a DoT effect *at compile time*.  In the next revision of your game, you might want to have a weapon that gains DoT at some point in time (e.g. when the user switches it to a different mode or when it has not been fired for 10 seconds).  If you make that decision, you'll probably have to change all of your code to use Option 1 or Option 2.

**A point about absolutism**

I see other people who support option 3 saying things like "absolutely correct" and "end of story".  You shouldn't believe them!  Design patterns are not rules.  There is more than one way to write good code.  What really matters is that your code is easy to read, easy to write, easy to change in the future, is not unnecessarily dangerous, and does the intended job.

Answer (score 1):

> not all weapons have a DoT

Then the base class of all weapons should not offer `getDoT`. End of story.

> but since my abstract class is Weapon, I would still need a check to see if the the weapon has a DoT, and then typecast from Weapon to Weapon_With_DoT to access the Weapon_With_DoT::getDoT

This way lies madness.

Instead of code that looks like this

```
if (I can haz DoT) {
  DoT = gets DoT from weapon somehow // null pointer or optional or dynamic_cast 
  doSomethingImportant(DoT)
}
```

try code that looks like this

```
weapon->doSomethingImportant();
```

where `doSomethingImportant` is a virtual function. It does something with DoT, or does nothing, or does something with something other than DoT. *You don't care what it does*, you know it's the right thing for this kind of weapon.

If you cannot add `doSomethingImportant` to `Weapon` for whatever reason (and there can be legitimate reasons), try doing the same thing with [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: In general, any (yes, *any*, this is no joke) `if` statement in your code is suspect and probably should be replaced like shown above. Exceptions should be rare.

Comment: If goal is to eliminate `if`s then I would consider any form of messaging, like: `weapon->process(Event("reload"));`

Comment: @c-smile it's not really a goal, it's means to achieve an end (clean maintainable code). But yeah,  a messaging system could be useful too.

Comment: I posted a question for n.m. in this chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95187/remove-if-from-c-code

Answer (score 1):

In cases like yours it makes sense to consider any sort of runtime polymorphism. Like dynamic cast or something like this:

```
class Weapon {
  enum { CLASS_ID: 1 };

  public:
    template<typename T>
    T* get_interface() {
      return static_cast<T*>(this->get_interface_by_id(T::CLASS_ID));
    }
    virtual Weapon* get_interface_by_id(int class_id) {
      if( class_id == CLASS_ID ) return this;
      return nullptr; // no other interfaces by default 
    }
}

class WeaponWithDot: public Weapon {
  enum { CLASS_ID: 2 };

  virtual Weapon* get_interface_by_id(int class_id) override {
      if( class_id == CLASS_ID ) return this;
      return Weapon::get_interface_by_id(class_id); 
    }
}
```

This way you can still operate instances of Weapon and request *dynamically* their features and functionality:

```
Weapon* some = ...;

WeaponWithDoT* with_dot = some->get_interface<WeaponWithDoT>();
if (with_dot) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Then remove the Dot data from `Weapon` class so it remains clean and inherit from it as a `DotWeapon`. you can still have the polimorphism of `Weapon` from object derived from `DotWeapon`.

> I thought about not having the DoT member/getDoT member function in
>   the first place, and just implement them on a derived class
>   Weapon_With_DoT, but since my abstract class is Weapon, I would still
>   need a check to see if the the weapon has a DoT, and then typecast
>   from Weapon to Weapon_With_DoT to access the Weapon_With_DoT::getDoT
>   member function. It's also unelegant, just the other way around.

You didn't grasped polimorphism completly.
Base classes should know nothing about derived classes. they only know what they contain, and it's up for their derived classes to fill the gaps.